# Add a paragraph under billing address WooCommerce checkout field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to add HTML tag `<p>` under the `Billing_Address_2` field. I read some documentation and tried this code:

```
function red_text() {
    echo '<p class="red_text" style="color:red;float:left;display:none">Hello World</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_billing_address_2_field', 'red_text' );
```

However, when I put it in my function.php theme, it just doesn't add the tag. Is there another way to add an html tag in the checkout page? If not, is my code wrong?

Comment: That action doesn't exist so your code is never fired.

Comment: I see. I saw that action in some website, so I thought there was something wrong with my woocommerce. Is there another way to add a html tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add HTML to the checkout page after order notes
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<p class="red_text" style="color:red;">Hello World</p>';

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following will add a custom paragraph (html `<p>` tag) under the Billing Address 2:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_text','additional_paragraph_after_billing_address_2', 10, 4 );
function additional_paragraph_after_billing_address_2( $field, $key, $args, $value ){
    if ( is_checkout() && $key == 'billing_address_2' ) {
        $field .= '<p class="form-row red_text" style="color:red;">Hello World</p>';
    }
    return $field;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

[image]